# making a sub-query FROM two tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT staffNO, name, surname, position
FROM Staff s, Branch b
WHERE s.branchNo = b.branchNo AND city = 'London';
```

I have tried to make the above SQL code into a sub-query and I'm not getting anywhere. Im a beginner in SQL, how do I go about it?

Comment: do you receive any error messages?

Comment: i tried it with WHERE EXSIST() statement..

Comment: no the code works but i would like to try it as a sub-query..

Comment: What do you mean ? A subquery of what query ? What is the query in which you want to put that subquery ? What have you tried ? What "did not work" ?

Answer (score 4):

The equivalent query with a sub-query and `IN` clause would look like this:

```
SELECT staffNO, name, surname, position
FROM Staff s
WHERE s.branchNo IN (
    SELECT b.branchNo
    FROM Branch b
    WHERE b.city = 'London'
);
```

This of course assumes that `staffNO, name, surname, position` are all available as fields on the `Staff` table.  If any of those fields come from `Branch` then you do need to use the `JOIN` syntax instead.

Comment: i have seen my error now..i used WHERE s.branchNo EXISTS(SELECT b.branchNo FROM Branch b) before and couldn't figure out how to include the city. thanks again